# disable button on certain select checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox

I had condition in my reactive `form` where one `checkbox` selected, submit `button` will be enabled, and if there are none `checkbox` selected, it will remain disabled, the problem is I had `selectAll` function, which if I clicked, it will selected all the checkbox and enabled submit `button`, then if I unselect individual `checkbox` **after select all function**, the submit button should be enabled until all the checkbox is unselect, this is what I had tried:

**ts file**

```
  selectAll() {
    this.formReceivedSummons.controls.map(value => value.get('isChecked').setValue(true));
    return this.disabledButton = false;
  }

  changeCheck(event){
    this.disabledButton = !event.target.checked;
  }
```

**html file**

```
<div *ngIf="isShowResponse">
    <p>Inquiry Response</p>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckboxes()">
        <ng-container formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let 
            summon of formReceivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked"
        (change)="changeCheck($event)">
  {{ summon.get('isChecked').value ? 'selected' : 'select' }}
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <button [disabled]="disabledButton">Submit</button>
</form>
<button (click)="selectAll()">Select All</button>
</div>
```

supposed to be after `select all` function, submit button will enabled until all `checkbox` is unselected individually then it will disabled, this is my  [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq4wxc?file=src/app/inquiry-response/inquiry-response.component.ts), I could use any suggestion to solve this problem,

Comment: You have to maintain an array to store values for all checkboxes. So with select all, the value of all items in array is true.  When any individual checkbox is unchecked, you make the value false in array for that checkbox. To disable Submit button, it will be disabled if all items in the array are false, else true.

Answer (score 1):

the "clasic solution" is make a custom error validator

Imagine that you has some like

```
  options=["option 1","option 2","option 2"]
  form=new FormGroup({
      prop1:new FormControl(),
      receivedSummons:new FormArray(this.options.map(x=>new FormControl()),this.selectAtLeastOne())
  })

  selectAtLeastOne()
  {
    return (formArray:FormArray)=>{
      return formArray.value.some(x=>x)?null:{error:"At least one"}
    }
  }
```

You only need

```
  <button [disabled]="form.invalid">submit</button>
```

The completed form is like

```
  <div [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="prop1">
  <div formArrayName="receivedSummons">
    <div *ngFor="let control of form.get('receivedSummons').controls;let i=index" >
      <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">{{options[i]}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="form.invalid">submit</button>
  </div>
```

NOTE: I choose use a formArray of FormControls, not a FormArray of formGroups, if you want to use a formArray of FormGroups, the code becomes like

```
  form2=new FormGroup({
      prop1:new FormControl(),
      receivedSummons:new FormArray(
         this.options.map(x=>new FormGroup({
           isChecked:new FormControl()
           })),this.selectAtLeastOne2())
  })

  selectAtLeastOne2()
  {
    return (formArray:FormArray)=>{
      return formArray.value.some(x=>x.isChecked)?null:{error:"At least one"}
    }
  }
```

And the .html

```
  <div [formGroup]="form2">
  <input formControlName="prop1">
  <div formArrayName="receivedSummons">
    <div *ngFor="let control of form.get('receivedSummons').controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" >
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked">{{options[i]}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="form2.invalid">submit</button>
  </div>
```

You can see the two forms in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7id4cs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Updated** I add two funtions to check/uncheck all

```
  selectAll(select: boolean) {
    this.form.get("receivedSummons").setValue(this.options.map(x => select));
  }

  selectAll2(select: boolean) {
    this.form2.get("receivedSummons").setValue(
      this.options.map(x => {
        return { isChecked: select };
      })
    );
  }
```

The check to check/uncheck all like (see as I use a refernce variable to pass if is checkd or not the checkBox

```
  <input #check1 type="checkbox" (change)="selectAll(check1.checked)">Check All
```

Comment: This is great,  feel I gave him a immediate solution only. But your idea is totally welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In html, define a reference in input "`#checkboxes`"

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked" #checkboxes (click)="changeCheck()">
```

In ts,

We can get all checkbox values using `@ViewChildren`

```
@ViewChildren("checkboxes") checkboxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

`ViewChildren`, `QueryList`, `ElementRef` to be imported from '`angular/core`'

```
changeCheck(){
    let flag= true;
     this.checkboxes.forEach((element) => { // loop all checkboxes to find checked boxes
      if(element.nativeElement.checked){
        flag=false // if atleast one checkbox checked, put the flag flase
      }
    });

    this.disabledButton = flag;
  }
```

Working code at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhxhzw)

Comment: Varman, your solution works, but I think that it's not an "angular solution". The clasic solution is make a custom validator

Comment: @jajanato if this answer is useful, please upvote and click tick to help others who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```js
  changeCheck(event){
    let flag = true
    for (let summon of this.formReceivedSummons.controls){
      if(summon.get('isChecked').value) {
        flag = false
      }
    }
    this.disabledButton = flag
  }
```